Using graphClient, successfuly created meeting does not show up in Calendar
I am creating a Teams meeting using graphClient successfully with the following code:
var meeting = new OnlineMeeting
{
    Subject = "demo meeting for user",
    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10),
    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(30),
    RecordAutomatically = true,
    Participants = new MeetingParticipants
    {
        Organizer = new MeetingParticipantInfo
        {
            Identity = new IdentitySet
            {
                User = new Identity
                {
                    Id = userid
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var result = await _graphClient.Users[userid].OnlineMeetings.PostAsync(meeting);

Using the meeting link in the result variable I can join to the meeting. Also I see the recording is automatically on, according the my meeting variable's RecordAutomatically = true.
However if I use the Teams app, and logging on as user which's guid is in the userid variable, I do not see the meeting in the Calendar.
What am I missing?

When you use the onlinemeeting endpoint that's to be expected

This API creates a standalone meeting that isn't associated with any
event on the user's calendar; therefore, meetings created via this API
aren't shown on the user's calendar.

ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
If you want to create a Meeting that shows up in the calendar and is a Online Teams meeting you need to use Create Event see the sample in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting and set the isOnlineMeeting property

Many thx. Unfortunatelly I have to create an onlinemeeting, where some attributes are set, for example start automatic recording. As far as I reviewed the event api does not provide setting attributes for the meeting, "just" creates an onlinemeeting if the isOnlineMeeting property is true

In that case you need a three step process first create the Online Meeting using the Events API which will return the joinurl, then use that to get the MeetingId for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http than use that Id to modify the Online specific properties using the online meeting endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
